# Silverlight: Syntax question for setting values

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I'm using Silverlight 4. The following XAML works fine:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="WrapPanelTemplate">
        <toolkit:WrapPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

    <ItemsControl x:Name="restOfHits" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding RestOfHits}" 
                  ItemsPanel="{StaticResource WrapPanelTemplate}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FileTemplate}"
                  Width="500"
                  Margin="0,50,0,0"
                  />
```

However, the following causes VS to complain:

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="restOfHits" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding RestOfHits}" 
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FileTemplate}"
                  Width="500"
                  Margin="0,50,0,0"
                  >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel />
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The error:

> Property 'ItemsPanel' does not support
>   values of type 'WrapPanel'.

Why is this? What is the proper way to specify that the `ItemsControl` should use a `WrapPanel` if I don't want to use Resources?

Answer (score 2):

Because ItemsPanel is expecting to receive an `ItemsPanelTemplate` and not anything else.
You are doing that in your first sample but not in your second.  Your second should look like this:-

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="restOfHits"  
              ItemsSource="{Binding RestOfHits}"  
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FileTemplate}" 
              Width="500" 
              Margin="0,50,0,0" 
              > 
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel> 
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>  
            <toolkit:WrapPanel />  
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel> 
</ItemsControl>
```